# How to properly create an object to be used by other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn javascript, and at the moment am playing around with the Kata Evercraft challenge.

Long story short I need to create a character, this character will have a name, stats, health, etc as part of this object.  I have defined a 'Character' class, in case I want to have multiple characters to play around with.  The character object will be created in the 'nameEntry()' function as the first thing a user will do is decide on a name.  Later on other functions will access this object and add stats, adjust health, or call up information to be displayed as necessary.

I have been told that creating the object as a global variable is a thing to generally avoid when programming, but I'm not 100% sure what to do to make this object accessible elsewhere without it being global.

My first attempt had me setting this variable as global by declaring it with window. in the function.  That works but makes it global obviously....

Here is my code so far for this bit, I have a console.log function being called just to test if my object is accessible.  obviously with my code currently I am getting an error thrown because character1 is not defined.  How should I best remedy this?

```
class Character {
    constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;}
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

}


const nameEntry = () => {
    let name = prompt("Enter your name: ", "name");
    const character1 = new Character(name);
    console.log(character1.name);
    document.getElementById("nameText").innerHTML = character1.name;
    if (character1.name != 'name') {
        $( ".button" ).remove();
    }
}

const displayName = () => {
    console.log(character1.name);
}
```

If my code worked as expected then calling the displayname() function would display what was entered in the prompt and set as 'name' within the character1 object.

Comment: Well displayName can not access character1 since it is defined in it and is not global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayName` is not working as expected because the `character1` variable only exists inside the `nameEntry` function.  If you want to avoid global variables, your `nameEntry` function should return the Character and the `displayName` function should accept Character as an argument.

```
const displayName = (character) => {
  console.log(character.name);
}
```

Comment: To do that though I would need to have one of the functions as a callback right?  The 'returned' character isn't going to just float in space until I call displayName at an indeterminate time?

Comment: It is not clear what your project structure is. You do need to store it somewhere and that somewhere might be global scope.  At some point, something has to be in the global scope.